# Why do I get an "Error in Parse" for && operator in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, logical-operators

ed_error is a dataframe with two columns.
I want to go through all rows one by one and add 1 to the variable I created, only if the string name of the value in the first column is equal to "general" and the integer value of the second column is equal to 1.

[image]

This is how the data looks like.

The code:

```
general_list <- 0

for (row in 1:nrow(ed_error)) {
    if (ed_error[row, 1] == "general") && (ed_error[row, 2] == 1) {
        general_list <- general_list + 1 }
                               }
```

The error:

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src):
5: for (row in 1:nrow(ed_error)) {
6:     if (ed_error[row, 1] == "general") &&
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `)` for `if` ends before the `&&`

```
 if (ed_error[row, 1] == "general")
```

i.e.

```
> if('a' == 'b') && ('c' == 'd')
Error: unexpected '&&' in "if('a' == 'b') &&"
```

Instead it would be

```
general_list <- 0
for (row in 1:nrow(ed_error)) {
if(ed_error[[1]][row] == "general" && ed_error[[2]][row] == 1) {
     general_list <- general_list + 1
    }
}
```

---

We may also use a vectorized option

```
general_list <- nrow(subset(ed_error, education %in% 'general' & error %in% 1))
```

Comment: Thank you, I got confused about the brackets. I've just started learning R.

Answer (score 3):

In R, most of the things would not require explicit `for` loops. This comparison can be done in vectorized way and use `sum` to count how many times the condition is satisfied.

```
general_list <- sum(ed_error$education == "general" & ed_error$error == 1)
```

If there are `NA` values in the data you may add `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum`.